# Solr multiple keyword search

Tags: solr

I'm trying to implement a search function and everything is working fine with the following code:

```
    String fl = "*" // information solr will send back
    String rows = (String) amount // amount of results

    (terms).each{
    String term = "${it}"
    def response = sendRequest("http://localhost:8983/solr/bookdata/select?q=title%3A+*"+term+"*%0Aisbn%3A+*"+term+"*%0Aannotation%3A+*"+term+"*%0Ablurb%3A+*"+term+"*&fl="+fl+"&rows="+ rows + "&wt=json&indent=true&omitHeader=true") 
    String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())

    println(data)
    return data

}
```

Json is succesfully recieved.

I have been looking for a few days on how to implement a multikeyword search. Right now I just send a request per keyword, which is not the way to go....

Any pointers on how to implement a multiple keyword search?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to search on multiple key terms per field, then you simply add some boolean clauses. For example:

`(title:termA OR title:termB) OR (isbn:termA OR isbn:termB)`

You can also use AND, of course, if that fits your use case. You may need to experiment with the logical groupings a bit to get the data you want.